# Getting latitude and longitude of polyline on map?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geometry-service

I have a code, that allows me to construct a polyline on the map, which I edited from [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=graphics_add) . The thing I want is to take the coordinates of the points clicked. I came up with

```
function myClickHandler(event) {
  alert("User clicked at " +
    event.screenPoint.x + ", " + event.screenPoint.y +
    " on the screen. The map coordinate at this point is " +
    event.mapPoint.x + ", " + event.mapPoint.y
  );
}
```

from [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/inside_events.html), but was not able to use both techniques in one code. Is there a way for coordinates of the chosen polyline points to be seen?

Comment: Stephan, do you want to get back the coordinates in the same spatial reference as your map? If not, what's the projection of your map?  Is it web mercator or geographic or something else?

Comment: you wnat to alert coordiante for every ploygone draw click ?